# List filter with binary pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```js
let listFilter = [0,7,5,4,1,3,5];
let pattern = [0,1,0,0];


function FilterByPattern(listToFilter, pattern){
    let variable = 0;

    while(variable < listToFilter.length){
        for(i of pattern){
            if(variable < listToFilter.length){
                if(i == 0){
                    listToFilter.splice(variable,1);
                }else{
                    variable += 1;
                }
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return listToFilter;
}

console.log(FilterByPattern(listFilter, pattern))
```

Hi,

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of filtering a list with another list pattern (of 1´s and 0´s) as done above.

The problem with the code is that It makes more iterations than the number of items listToFilter has. I´m trying to do It without having to create any other list.

Thank you!

Comment: @NinaScholz my guess is that it's literally bits for a number. The result is `7, 3` both of which have the same bit set on them. If so, this should be bitwise OR-able. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the logic here; if `pattern` is a considered as bitmask then filtered array should be `[7, 5, 4, 5]` since contains the 3rd bit set to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the array by taking the value of the pattern by using the remainder operator and the length of the pattern as index.

```js
const
    filterByPattern = (array, pattern) => array.filter((_, index) =>
        pattern[index % pattern.length]);

console.log(filterByPattern([0, 7, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 0, 0]));
```

A mutating approach by keeping the array.

```js
const
    filterByPattern = (array, pattern) => {
        let index = array.length;

        while (index--) 
            if (!pattern[index % pattern.length])
                array.splice(index, 1);

        return array;
    };

console.log(filterByPattern([0, 7, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 0, 0]));
```

Comment: OK, seems I was wrong with the binary representation of numbers being related. Now that I think of it, even then the bitmask doesn't make sense as it should be matching `5` but not `3`.

Comment: Is there a way to do It just changing the original list rather than creating another one?